# The hard drive on my device is 32gigs but Linux Mint installer says there is only 15.7gigs and that it requires 16.1gigs, what do I do?

Tags: partitioning, linux-mint, lenovo-laptop, storage

The hard drive on my device is 32gigs but Mint Linux installer says there is only 15.7gigs and that it requires 16.1gigs, what do I do?

I have cleared all the partitions and it hasn't changed, I don't dare restart the device after clearing the partitions.

Is there hidden partitions? See:

```
boot-repair-4ppa200                                              [20240125_0205]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/mmcblk1 and looks at 
    sector 16412968 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not 
    be found at this location.

mmcblk1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.3, virginia, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: (4.0) from coreboot
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________


Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________


fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk mmcblk1: 14.56 GiB, 15634268160 bytes, 30535680 sectors
Disk sda: 14.59 GiB, 15664676864 bytes, 30595072 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xd548b2ee
      Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *         64  5990687  5990624  2.9G  0 Empty
sda2          8364    18475    10112  4.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sda3       5992448 30595071 24602624 11.7G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:15.7GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:SanDisk Cruzer Blade:;
mmcblk1boot0:4194kB:sd/mmc:512:512:unknown:Generic SD/MMC Storage Card:;
mmcblk1boot1:4194kB:sd/mmc:512:512:unknown:Generic SD/MMC Storage Card:;
mmcblk1:15.6GB:sd/mmc:512:512:unknown:MMC AGND3R:;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME         FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                           PARTLABEL
sda          iso9660  2024-01-09-12-59-13-00                                                    Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon 64-bit 
├─sda1       iso9660  2024-01-09-12-59-13-00               d548b2ee-01                          Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon 64-bit 
├─sda2       vfat     659D-4321                            d548b2ee-02                                                          
└─sda3       ext4     a2b9bf6c-d2a1-4cbd-9733-9bbe5620d7c6 d548b2ee-03                          writable                        
mmcblk1                                                                                                                         
mmcblk1boot0                                                                                                                    
mmcblk1boot1                                                                                                                    

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                             Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2024-01-25.0/log]  10.8G   0% /var/log
/dev/sda1                                                        0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2024-01-25.0/log] ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1                                                   iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on mmcblk1p1


Unknown BootLoader on sda

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f3 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 02  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  31 c9 5a 51 b4 08 cd 13  5b 0f b6 c6 40 50 83 e1  |1.ZQ....[...@P..|
00000080  3f 51 f7 e1 53 52 50 bb  00 7c b9 04 00 66 a1 b0  |?Q..SRP..|...f..|
00000090  07 e8 44 00 0f 82 80 00  66 40 80 c7 02 e2 f2 66  |..D.....f@.....f|
000000a0  81 3e 40 7c fb c0 78 70  75 09 fa bc ec 7b ea 44  |.>@|..xpu....{.D|
000000b0  7c 00 00 e8 83 00 69 73  6f 6c 69 6e 75 78 2e 62  ||.....isolinux.b|
000000c0  69 6e 20 6d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 72 20 63 6f  |in missing or co|
000000d0  72 72 75 70 74 2e 0d 0a  66 60 66 31 d2 66 03 06  |rrupt...f`f1.f..|
000000e0  f8 7b 66 13 16 fc 7b 66  52 66 50 06 53 6a 01 6a  |.{f...{fRfP.Sj.j|
000000f0  10 89 e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b  c0 e4 06 88 e1 88 c5 92  |...f.6.{........|
00000100  f6 36 ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1  41 b8 01 02 8a 16 f2 7b  |.6.{....A......{|
00000110  cd 13 8d 64 10 66 61 c3  e8 1e 00 4f 70 65 72 61  |...d.fa....Opera|
00000120  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 20 6c 6f 61 64  |ting system load|
00000130  20 65 72 72 6f 72 2e 0d  0a 5e ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62  | error...^....>b|
00000140  04 b3 07 cd 10 3c 0a 75  f1 cd 18 f4 eb fd 00 00  |.....<.u........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  2c 48 00 00 00 00 00 00  ee b2 48 d5 00 00 80 02  |,H........H.....|
000001c0  01 00 00 b6 e0 fe 40 00  00 00 e0 68 5b 00 00 fe  |......@....h[...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff ac 20  00 00 80 27 00 00 00 03  |....... ...'....|
000001e0  4f 75 83 74 c4 70 00 70  5b 00 00 68 77 01 00 00  |Ou.t.p.p[..hw...|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200
```

This device is a Lenovo N23 was previously running Chrome OS 103 until I bricked the Chrome OS when flashing SeaBIOS.

It is an Intel core (Braswell).

The board is Reks.

---

**Edit**: For those wanting proof of the hard drive size here it is:

[image: System Info]

Also here is the processor info:

- Intel© Celeron© CPU  N3060  @ 1.60GHz × 2

Also when using the disks program it only shows the USB flash drive (16GB), SD card reader and 2.6GB loop device.

Comment: Lenovo N23 has been sold with different configurations, 16 or 32GB eMMC drive (not an hard drive!) (and 2 or 4GB RAM, also somewhat relevant here, 4GB is the practical minimum for a mainstream desktop Linux distro). **fdisk says it's 16GB. So, how exactly have you concluded it has 32GB?**

Comment: What @ChanganAuto said. Your computer is telling you it has the 16GB eMMC drive. What makes you believe the system has 32GB of storage, and is there a reason to disbelieve what your computer is saying about itself?

Comment: Prove for yourself the size of the drive. Boot from USB, e.g. a Live Mint USB (https://itsfoss.com/linux-mint-live-usb/). Run *Disks* utility. Look at total space on drive. Perhaps the drive is 16 GB -- pretty much useless. Perhaps it has two partitions of 16 GB, 32 GB total, and they can be removed to make 32 GB of free space -- minuscule, but installation should be doable.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have added the image of the system info stating it is a 33.9GB HardDrive, I know it has more than 16GB because when on chromeos the system was taking 16GB & I was still able to download large files to the device.

Comment: No, what is showing is the sum of your USB stick and the internal eMMC and the loop device created by the live session; notice the "hard drives" (plural). No, the ChromeOS in 16GB storage devices takes less than that so you always have *some* free space, it all depends on the apps you install, personal files, etc. But all of this is moot, `fdisk` and `parted agree: **Disk mmcblk1: 14.56 GiB** and **mmcblk1:15.6GB**; `sda` is your USB stick. Really, nothing else to say, you're mistaken or you were scammed. You may try the use Disks to have a graphical representation (why didn't you already?)

Comment: PS - Sorry, haven't noticed you last edit - *when using the disks program it only shows the USB flash drive (16GB), SD card reader and 2.6GB loop device* -. That's all there is. **"SD card reader" IS your internal eMMC drive**, that's it, nothing else, eMMC and SD are very similar, almost interchangeable technologies, reason why Disks always shows eMMCs like plain SD cards, end of story.

Comment: Also, "running Chrome OS 103." Chromebooks are very much closed systems. From all I've read, installing another OS is difficult, and you might be experiencing an issue due to firmware, as well. See https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=258363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The hard drive on my device is 32gigs but Mint Linux installer says there is only 15.7gigs and that it requires 16.1gigs, what do I do?

Unfortunately, nothing to do here. The installer is correct, you're mistaken. Your internal drive, the eMMC,the only one that can be used to install an OS, is in fact **~16GB**, not 32GB.

The Boot Repair script shown in the question ran both `fdisk` and `parted`. Both tools can and will show the total available space, irrespective of unallocated space and/or "hidden" partitions.

`fdisk`:

```
Disk mmcblk1: 14.56 GiB, 15634268160 bytes, 30535680 sectors
```

`parted`:

```
mmcblk1:15.6GB
```

And this is it, absolutely nothing else. The Mint's system information panel you added to the question shows the sum of all the drives present, the eMMC, the USB stick from where the live session is running and the ("virtual") loop devices.

The [Lenovo N23 Chromebook](https://www.lenovo.com/il/en/laptops/lenovo/student-chromebooks/N23-Chromebook/p/88ELC1S0873?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) has been sold with 16 or 32GB eMMC and with 2 or 4GB RAM. Other differences are in the displays (not relevant) and CPUs (relevant). **The model with Intel® Celeron® N3060 comes with the lower specifications (2GB RAM / 32GB eMMC)**.